# How To Use nextTick() With Focus Ref in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm migrating my code from vue 2 to vu 3. I want to make the contents of a textarea on the autofocus, but what happens is an error message `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: content.value.focus is not a function.` Here is my code:

```
<textarea 
ref="content" 
cols="30" 
rows="10" 
class="input" 
placeholder="Paste your HTML here"
v-model="content">
</textarea>
```

```
<script setup>
import { nextTick, onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const modalShown = ref(false);
let existingBlot = ref(null);
const content = ref('');

const applyHTML = () => {
    emit('adding', {
        content: content,
        existingBlot: existingBlot,
    });

    close();
}

const close = () => {
    modalShown.value = false;
    content.value = '';
    existingBlot = null;
}

onMounted(() => {
    emitter.on('openingHTMLEmbedder', data => {
        if (data) {
            content = data.content;
            existingBlot = data.existingBlot;
        }
        nextTick(() => { content.value.focus() })
        modalShown.value = true;
    });
});

</script>
```

i don't have any idea where is the mistake, or how to solve this.
so, I'm glad that anyone here can help me by giving me some suggestions to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's unknown how openingHTMLEmbedder, data, etc work, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. `content = data.content` - this is a mistake, never reassign ref var.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

> setTimeout(()=>{content.value.focus()},0)

Comment: it works for me but I cannot understand why! any explanation? thanks anyway :)